# Colour difference in plot between normal variable and factor variable

Tags: r, plot, colors

I am using `plot` function on mtcars dataset.

I am trying to add colour to the plots based on `mtcars$cyl` variable

The distinct values in cyl variable is  4,6 and 8

First i tried this:

```
plot(x=mtcars$wt, y=mtcars$mpg, col = mtcars$cyl)
```

I got points plotted on **blue,purple and grey** colour.

Then I converted `cyl` variable into a factor and tried the same plot again,

```
mtcars$fcyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

plot(x=mtcars$wt, y=mtcars$mpg, col = mtcars$fcyl)
```

But this time I got **black,red and green**

I want to understand how assigning the variable as factor changes the colour. What happens behind?

Comment: factor is converting your continuous data in categorial data (basically integers), the factors may not be in the same order as the sorted numbers, and I guess with factors `plot` try to space evenly the values on the palette. With continuous values obviously two close value will be assigned to close colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to understand how assigning the variable as factor changes the colour. What happens behind?

In R, factors are just integers under the hood.  In the plot function, integers are converted to eight different colors (repeating), which are 8 colors that can be visually separated.

Try this:

```
plot(x=1:16, y=1:16, col = 1:16, pch=16)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't completely understand. Are you saying that original value (4,6,8) will be converted to integer numbers internally if you use factor? Based on the colour it looks like they have been converted to 1,2 and 3. Is that correct?

Comment: try `as.numeric(factor(mtcars$cyl))`

Comment: Thank you. Understood :)